# MOSS (SharePoint) publishing page schedule options not appearing

Tags: sharepoint, moss, site-definition

I'm building a custom publishing site definition for MOSS 2007 but I seem to have a problem. The content types that I import don't have any of the page scheduling options available.

I've gone over my onet.xml next to the one which the Publishing Site uses (in the BLANKINTERNET folder) and I am putting in all the features which are in the standard one.

I'm new to the publishing definition scene so I'm not quite sure what I've done wrong to drop off the scheduling options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the solution to this problem here - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/042a59a2-9889-4894-8785-18eebf63872d/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this can help but maybe can give you some direction to look. There are three BLANKINTERNET templates:

1. **BLANKINTERNET#0** 
   Publishing site - A site for publishing web pages on a schedule with workflow features enabled
2. **BLANKINTERNET#1** 
   Press releases site
3. **BLANKINTERNET#2**
   Publishing site with workflow—A publishing site for web
   pages using approval workflows

Comment: Yeah I've been over them with a fine-toothed comb. Don't know why it isn't being activated, I have worked out how to programmatically do it though, kind of solves the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2007/01/11/how-to-enable-scheduled-publishing-in-a-moss-collaboration-portal.aspx